# Removing stripe or decal glue from exterior paint

Tags: ford, paint

I bought a Ford Fiesta Zetec and the previous owner has removed the stripes that run over the middle of the car, which has left a terrible looking mark, as if the glue has not come off when they removed the stripes.

What's the best way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use some WD-40 and a little elbow grease and it should come right off. Spray the WD-40 right onto the glue residue, then wipe off with a soft cloth. This will destroy the cloth in the process by having the glue residue build up on it, but the glue will be off your vehicle. When you have cleaned the entire area, ensure you wash the vehicle, as what's left of the WD-40 will attract dust. A good coat of wax afterward will help as well.

**Please note:** When I specify **WD-40**, I mean use it and not something else. WD-40 was originally designed to clean the skin on aircraft. It will work as I'm describing. I cannot vouch for any other type of spray lubricant.

Comment: http://imgur.com/CWYrl03    http://imgur.com/bvkuWAM     Just a few pictures just so you can see what it is i have tried wd 40 on a small part of it and it has helped but still leaves marks

Comment: @LiamDrew - Wow, that's ugly. Probably going to take more than WD-40 to get that off, but it'll get the glue residue off. Once that is off, we can see what's going on and what's left and help you from there. It just may be all of the gunk left over and once that is gone, you'll be golden.

Comment: yeah the area i have WD-40 ed has made it look slightly better but still marks i will try and finish it all tommorow as its going dark here now but thanks  alot

Comment: @LiamDrew - You'll need to get rid of all of the glue residue before you can work on the finish. If you don't, you'll only be frustrated and gum up whatever you are trying to use to clean up the mess.

Comment: try heating the area with a hot rag or hair dryer on warm (not hot) don't keep it in one place too long as it could damage the paint.  Just basically trying to warm the gum up to help soften it, you could also try judicious use of white spirits.

Comment: Okay so I've pretty much got it all off thanks for all your help I WD-40'd the whole are and then t cut the area and it has got rid of about 90% of it just a few marks where the scratches were deep but cant really notice them just thought I would comment this in case anyone else has my problem. If you do have it like mine do make sure to WD-40 the area first !

Answer (score 1):

Can also use brake and clutch spray cleaner test on hidden area first but this will remover almost every thing also amazing for cleaning alloy wheels.